# Why the 8080 port is occupied by file explorer?

Tags: windows-10, port

I want to use the port 8080, but it has been occupied.
I used the command

> netstat -aon|findstr "8080"

The PID is 29344, and the program is file explore.
Why is it happened, and how to change it?

Comment: This is not about programming.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Port 8080 is reserved for the web client proxy.

See [this Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/service-overview-and-network-port-requirements) page.

Comment: But it is occupied by my file explorer now. So how to solve it?